# How to link LYX with MikTex on Win XP?

Tags: pdf, windows-xp, virtualbox, lyx, miktex

I have MikTex and LYX installed on Win XP running in Virtualbox on Debian 8. MikTex on its own works fine, LYX as well. However, when I want to open dokument preview in LYX, it does not call MikTex and returns a "missing PDF file" error instead. LYX is supposed to use MikTex for generating PDF output; is there perhaps a possibility to configure LYX to link with MikTex?

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems in the past. Uninstalling both, LyX and MikTeX, and reinstalling the LyX-*Bundle* installer (not the simple one without MikTeX) got me bot running and working together.